# Reducer task in Hadoop not behaving as expected

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have 2 input files for a Hadoop MapRed task.

The input to the program is `input.txt` which contains in each row `PaperID keyword1 keyword2 FieldID`

```
p20 k j f3
p21 k j f11
p22 k j f3
p23 k j f2
p23 k j f1
```

The file `sammap.txt` used in the Reducer class contains in each row `FieldID FieldName`

```
f1 AI
f2 DB
f3 DB
f4 AI
```

The code is as follows:
    package dorado;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class Dorado {

  public static class TokenizerMapper
       extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text>{

    private Text word = new Text();
    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String str = value.toString().replaceAll(" +", " ").trim(), fir="", lst="";
        if (!str.equals("")) {
            fir = str.substring(0, str.indexOf(" "));
            lst = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);

            context.write(new Text(fir), new Text(lst));
        }


    }
  }

  public static class IntSumReducer
       extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text> {
  //  private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();
    private HashMap<Text, Text> fieldToClass = new HashMap<>();
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable <Text> value,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("sammap.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String str=null;
        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String st[] = str.split(" +");
            fieldToClass.put(new Text(st[0].trim()), new Text(st[1].trim()));

            //System.out.println("--"+st[0].trim()+"--"+ st[1].trim()+"--");
        }
        fr.close();

        for (Text field : value) {
            System.out.println(key + "-->" + field);

            if (fieldToClass.containsKey(field))
                context.write(key, fieldToClass.get(field));
        }

    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "dorado");
    job.setJarByClass(Dorado.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
  }
}
```

The Hashmap `fieldToClass` has the key as FieldID and value as FieldName.

The output on the console for the following code snippet in the Reducer Class:

```
for (Text field : value) {
    System.out.println(key + "-->" + field);
    if (fieldToClass.containsKey(field))
        context.write(key, fieldToClass.get(field));
}
```

is this:

```
p20-->DB
p22-->DB
p23-->AI
p23-->DB
```

However we would expect the output to be of the form:

```
p20-->f3
p22-->f3
p23-->f1
p23-->f2
```

Also there is no output in the final output file of the program. The file is empty.

The correct output we expect in the file is:

```
p20 DB
p22 DB
p23 DB
p23 AI
```

Why is the program behaving erroneously? What are the possible solutions?

Comment: However we would expect the output to be of the form:

p20-->f3
p22-->f3
p23-->f1
p23-->f2  are you sure?

Comment: I don't see why you're getting a different output with the code you posted. As you're printing a key and every value associated with it, you should have gotten every key and value pair that was emitted by the mapper. And always explicitly specify the number of reducers while submitting a job using `setNumReduceTasks()` method. And how are you running this job? In local or on a cluster?

Comment: @BurakKarasoy - Yes. On the console. And the output for the reducer on context is also mentioned separately in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your whole process can be done inside the mapper itself. Use setup function of mapper to initialize the HashMap. Directly search for the fieldId in the HashMap and get it's value and write it to context. Output the same thing in the reducer inside the for loop of the iterable value.